# install Lion on Imac with macbook-pro HDD copy

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, imac, install

Is it possible to do a new lion install on an imac if you copied/cloned the HDD of your macbook-pro (with CCC)?

In theory that is ofcourse, because it won't.

The installer log, mentions:

- missing of authentication module "ConfigurationProfiles"
- unable to find service discovery callback for module "PlistFile"
- and some more details

is there something I can do to fix?

**What I can not understand is why a complete copy of the macbook will make my imac work again, but I can not do a fresh install?**
This problem that I am trying to fix started out with the imac hanging in the grey screen. After that I try'd the normal things like cmd+R but it just did not install from the app store, wich led me to believe it was a hardware problem, bad sectors and all. But like I mentioned above, I am running lion now, but not the way I want to. I don't have anymore technical knowledge to understand this. **I just did the apple hardware test. Appaerantly I have a HDD error 1291;**

**UPDATE**

I researched the error from the apple test some more. Everything starting with MOT is related to the fan. I turned the computer off and pulled out the power cable. Then I hold the powerbutton for about 6 seconds. (read it somewhere, but I forgot the details). After a period of cooling of, I started again with the original SL DVD and it finally installed. The only thing was that I could not login for some reason. It also used the information from my previous attempts to install from the macbook copy. The login screen showed the computername of my macbook. CONCLUSION: This install still did not qualify as a fresh install. Next I erased the volumes again. This time I used the zero fill option. The next attempt to do  a install leaded to the same impossible error "can not install on this HDD". After reading some more in the install log and googling some more, the one thing that was keeping me curious and the log does not tell you that, is that the volume in diskutility shows "ownerEnabled=NO". It is not possible to change that in diskutility and as far as I know, not in terminal either. I made the change by using "TargetDisk" with my macbook. On the selected volume press CMD+I and change the setting in the bottom to Ignore ownership. Now I try'd to install Lion from my downloaded version right onto that volume. It took about 3 minutes. After I booted the imac without "targetdisc" It did not boot, instead you wil see a folder with a questionmark. Ok, the conclusion is that you cannot install lion when your booted from another computer. It just leaves an installfolder with some information if you inspect the volume.
After this I tr'd to do an install from the SL DVD again. I was waiting for it to fail again, but to my surprise, I got a fresh install and now I am downloading the software updates to get to version 10.6.6 wich is the minimal required to upgrade to Lion.
This endavour has cost me 4 days altogether, but I am happy it is 4 houers before I had an appointment with the genius-bar and I had to carry the imac al the way to the store.

Best thing I learnt from this, is to absolutely make a backup!

Because I cannot not with absolute certainty say it was because of the "ownership issue" because I did some other thing after, but I hope it can help someone being stuck like me.

Comment: since I have to type 15 characters to get to the answer = NO! get the OS X Installer from Apple store and than you can do it.

Comment: maybe I am not giving you the complete information, but that won't work, you need to have a recovery-hd or not, that'swhy I copied mine from my macbook

Comment: http://reviews.cnet.co.uk/software-and-web-apps/how-to-install-os-x-lion-on-multiple-macs-with-only-one-download-50004519/

Comment: thanks for the link, but what do you do when the imacs HDD is already erased, are there any logical steps to follow, will booting from the macbook with targetdisk work? I have not try'd that yet

Comment: OK, this might clarify it. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4788796?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: How old are any of these machines and what are you indtalling from?

Comment: imac is 2010 I think, macbook a little later, they both started out with leopard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method #1**

Do you have a Snow Leopard DVD? Install it on the iMac, make the Software Update, Download Lion from the App Store, Install it. Then boot the MacBook in Target Disk Mode and use Migration Assistant to import your Data to the iMac.

**Method #2** (if iMac is capable of Mountain Lion => if not, use MLPostFactor)

Download Mountain Lion on the MacBook via App Store, boot the iMac in Target Disk Mode and install it this way from the MacBook. After Install worked, use Migration Assistant.

Comment: I already tryd that, the leopard dvd won't install, it just gives out an error, installation not possible on this HDD, wich started me to think it really is a HDD problem, but I am running lion from the macbook kloon. This is just confusing. I do want to try one more time theleopard dvd on the new partition I made.

Comment: I will accept this answer, because it is the only one and a good one if my HDD was not broke.

Comment: Ok, I didn't thought about a broken disk…